# Responsive menu doesn't work when resizing

Tags: css, menu, hover, responsive-design, menuitem

I am working on a responsive website for myself and I am a little stuck with the menu.

When I resize to 670px screen my menu changes but my 2 bottom menu items don't work properly.

This is the code from the media query:

CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width:670px) {       
    nav select{
        display:none;
}

    nav ul:first-of-type{
        display: block;
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 1.4em;
    }

    nav ul li{
        border-top: black 1px solid;
        line-height: 2.5em;
    }

    nav ul li:last-of-type{
        border-bottom: black 1px solid;
    }

    nav ul li a{
        display: block;
    }

    nav ul li a:hover{
        opacity: .2;    
    }

    #video1{
        display: none;
    }

    #video2{
        display: block;
    }

    #bio{
        padding-top: 2em;   
    }

    p{
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    a{
        color: #000;
    }   
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#1">biography</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">illustration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">film</a></li>
            <li><a href="#4">tumblr</a></li>
            <li><a href="#5">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<nav>
    <select>
        <option value="#1" selected>Biography</option>
        <option value="#2">Illustration</option>
        <option value="#3">Film</option>
        <option value="#4">Tumblr</option>
        <option value="#5">Contact</option>
    </select> 
</nav>
```

you can check the live website on http://nickzijlstra.com/resp

Comment: When you say it's not working, are you talking about how Tumblr and Contact are inline with each other?

Comment: It's working how it's supposed to as far as I can tell. Please be more specific with your problem.

Comment: when changing the size of the window the bottom two menu items are not selectable. like they are no links

if you play with the window size you can see it

http://nickzijlstra/com/resp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Footer has a height of 50% which overlays the bottom couple nav buttons.

Play around with the z-index of the nav and that should get you where you need to go

Comment: Thank youu! added the z-index and position relative and it worked !!! thanks a lot